# composer require dompdf/dompdf not install

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.    Problem 1     - laravel/framework is locked to version v7.28.4 and an update of this package was not requested.     - laravel/framework v7.28.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirem

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1 || ^8.0 ||^7.2.5",
        
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0||^7.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0|^2.4.2",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6||^2.4.1",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0|^4.2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5 || ^8 || ^9"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: _your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement_

Answer (score 0):

dompdf above v1 and laravel 6,7,8 now support php 8, you just wrong dependencies version or operator.

Or operator in composer is `|`, so just change `||` to `|` in your composer.json, example:

```
"php": "^7.1 || ^8.0 ||^7.2.5",
"laravel/framework": "^8.0||^7.0",
```

to:

```
"php": "^7.1 | ^8.0 |^7.2.5",
"laravel/framework": "^8.0|^7.0",
```

But I think you need to define one, laravel 8 or 7.

And btw your php `^7.2.5` is wortless/will be ignored.

After update composer.json, don't forget to run `composer update` before install other depedency.